# Why is $|-x|=-x$ if $x<0$?

Tags: absolute-value

Here is the question:

> If $x < 0$, then what should $|-x|$ be equal to?

From my understanding, everything within the brackets should equate to a non-negative value. Which means no matter what number $x$ is, $|-x|$ should always be equal to a positive number but the book says it's equal to $-x$.

Let's say $x = -1$, then it would be $|-(-1)| = 1$, which is still a positive number.

So what am I getting wrong? I am very confused! Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Let's say $x = -1$, then it would be $|-(-1)| = 1$, which is still a positive number." Yes. $-x$ is positive. Not $x$. And so $|-x|=-x$. Just because there's a minus before $x$ it doesn't mean it is negative, it still depends on $x$.

Comment: If the symbol $\color{red}{«-»}$ confuses you, then immediately focus on simplifying it.  You know that, *by definition* $|x|=|-x|$. Therefore, you have $$|-x|=|x|=-x$$ where $x<0$ .

Comment: When $x$ is negative, $-x$ is positive.

Comment: "Let's say x=−1, then it would be |−(−1)|=1, which is still a positive number." Yes but $1$ is exactly $-x$ when $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is negative, then $-x$ is positive and the brackets $||$ do not influence the result, so you definitely get $-x$ as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Short observation that precedes thinking about absolute values: a numerical expression that starts with a $-$ sign does not necessarily represent a negative number.

That's exactly what your example shows. The  expression $-z$   starts with a $-$ sign. It may or may not evaluate to a negative number. That depends on whether $z$ is negative to begin with.